# Autoloading Hack type aliases

Tags: composer-php, hhvm, spl-autoload-register, psr-4, hacklang

Is there any way autoload Hack type aliases? I've placed them in separate files on PSR-4-compliant paths, and although I understand they are Hack-only and aren't formally mentioned in the PSR-0 or PSR-4, I figured one of the following would happen:

1. HHVM would expand type aliases to their base types, or
2. `spl_autoload` would treat the type as a class, function or interface name and execute the script, resolving the alias.

However, neither happen. At runtime, the methods call fail due to incompatibility with the type hints, i.e.:

> Catchable fatal error: Argument passed to {method_name} must be an instance of {type_alias}, {concrete_type} given.

**Edit**: I should mention that I am specifically using Composer. I'm unsure if this is Composer-specific or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can autoload types in HHVM. You need to be using a class-map approach and the [`HH\autoload_set_paths`](https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/reference/function/HH.autoload_set_paths/) function.

There is the [hhvm-autoload](https://github.com/fredemmott/hhvm-autoload) package which adds support for generating the necessary map into composer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible. PHP doesn't register type hints for autoloading. And it doesn't need to, because the only way to fulfill the type hint is to pass that class or subclasses, whose construction would've triggered the autoloader call. It is impossible then for a type hint to be unknown to the interpreter at the time it checks against it.

This is only a problem in Hack because type aliases introduce this possibility. To stay consistent with PHP, I expect the only viable solution of the two mentioned would be for HHVM to expand type aliases while compiling the bytecode.